# Quotation marks when saving on the firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem: When I save data in the Firebase, quotation marks (") always appear automatically in front of and behind the number. The problem is that the arduino does not accept the quotation marks... If you create a new variable in the firebase and this assigning a fixed number there are no quotation marks, so the problem must be with how the number is "uploaded" by Flutter.
On the attached picture you can see what I mean with the quotation marks. [image]

For understanding the code: First I get the new location, than the variable latitudee gets the value the latitude the new location has, than the variable latitudeRound becomes the var longitudee but roundet. Last but not least the variable latitudeRound will be saved.

```
_location.onLocationChanged.listen((l) {
      print((l.latitude));
      setState(() {
        latitudee = l.latitude;
        latitudeRound = latitudee.toStringAsFixed(5);
      });
    });

FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .update({'latitudeBoot': latitudeRound});
```

Comment: You will need to edit the question to show more of your code, in particular, what you did to create declare and assign `latitudeRound`.  Firebase does not modify data that you write - you have to provide the correct data.  Also it seems your screenshot is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is because of the datatype you are sending to firebase. If you send a string then you get "123" but if you send an int value you get 123

use this to parse your string to double before uploading it

```
var doubleValue = double. parse(latitudeRound);
```

then upload

```
[![FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .update({'latitudeBoot': doubleValue});
```